# How to select values from different datalist and display it in same textarea box at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm setting up a new website and want values from multiple datalist dropdown in a single textarea, I have tried below code :
I want output like this (https://ibb.co/1mJ2PVF) but i am getting output like this (https://ibb.co/YN369Gt).

This is for taking values from multiple datalist and store all values at a time in a text area, I've tried creating three datalist but when I select value from another datalist, the value from previous datalist gets replaced, i how can i make all values appear in textarea from all datalist?

```
         <input list="brown" name="exam">

                 <datalist id="brown">
                     <option value="Morning">
                     <option value="Afternoon">
                     <option value="Evening">
                     <option value="Night">

                 </datalist>

         <input list="brown1" name="exam">

                 <datalist id="brown1">

                     <option value="twice">
                     <option value="once">
                     <option value="thrice">


                 </datalist>  

          <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:20px;">
                   <textarea id="examination" rows="5" cols="130"> 
                   </textarea>
          </div>


          <script>
                $("input[name=exam]").on('change', function () {
                    $("#examination").text($(this).val());
                });
          </script>
```

i expect all values from different datalist appear in same textarrea box but now i am getting only one when i select next datalist the value from previous datalist gets replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `$("#examination").text($(this).val());` the content of `textarea` is replaced by currently selected dropdown value. Instead get all the dropdown fields, loop over it and get the value, finally add it to the `textarea`.

```js
const outputEle = $('#examination');
let outputText = "";

$("input[name=exam]").on('change', function() {
  $('input[name=exam]').each((i, input) => {
    let val = $(input).val();
    if (val) {
      outputText += val + '\n';
    }
  });
  outputEle.val(outputText);
  outputText = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="brown" name="exam">

<datalist id="brown">
        <option value="Morning">
        <option value="Afternoon">
        <option value="Evening">
        <option value="Night">

    </datalist>

<input list="brown1" name="exam">

<datalist id="brown1">

        <option value="twice">
        <option value="once">
        <option value="thrice">

    </datalist>

<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <textarea id="examination" rows="5" cols="130">
          </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
    $("input[name=exam]").on('change', function () {
        const text = $("#examination").val().trim() !== '' ? $("#examination").val() + '\n' + $(this).val() :  $(this).val()
        $("#examination").text(text);
    });
</script>
```